# probleme date importation by Talend ETL- postgres (django framework)

Tags: django, postgresql, date, etl, talend

I have very stange probleme with an date field,i can not find the answer on google
On start i have an CSV file, it crossing over an ETL (Talend, only tMap and tPostgresSqlOutput).
If i look debug , all are right, but when i answare my bdd the value of field is not the same (one day before)...

You can look my tests :
Talend debug result :

[image: talend debug]

Database datas

[image: talend debug]

\d table

[image: talend debug]

Where i must looking for ?

thx.

Comment: What do you get if you execute this query ?
`select to_char(date_sortie, 'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM table`

Comment: ` to_char
-------------
 06-AUG-2018
(1 ligne)
`